HttpProxyMiddleware [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END] when using agent
I'm using HttpProxyMiddleware, with those options:
const options = {
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
    onProxyReq,
    onProxyRes,
        agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(...),
        .....
       }

onProxyReq (for post requests):
function onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
    proxyReq.write(req.body);

When I get post requests, its failing due to [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]
If I dont use it, the post requests are sent without a body.
This is the middleware:
app.use(express.raw({ type: '*/*', limit: '50mb' }));
... { more middlewares that reads request body} ...
app.use(proxyMiddleware);

proxyMiddleware using createProxyMiddleware with the above options, and making a use of req.body.
I know that the body is empty since I read the stream with express.raw which using bodyParser behind the scenes, but how can I write it back again before its sent?
I cant make any request changes on 'onProxyReq', since I get errors like the above, and if I try to change any headers I get [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]
I want to write the request body back before I send it to the server
